# Matrix addition in python, float values

Tags: python

```
def compute_Jacobian_plus(J):
    J_t = J.transpose()
    print (J) 
    print(J_t)
    
    temp1 = np.matmul(J_t,J)
    temp2 = np.array([[lambdaa,0,0],[0,lambdaa,0],[0,0,lambdaa]])
    print(temp1)
    print(temp2)
    
    result = np.array([[0,0,0],
                    [0,0,0],
                    [0,0,0]])
 

    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            result[i][j] = temp1[i][j] + temp2[i][j]
 
    print (result)
    

J=compute_Jacobian()
compute_Jacobian_plus(compute_Jacobian())
```

On adding temp1 and temp2, I should be getting

```
[[10.001  0  0]
 [ 0  5.001  3]
 [ 0  3  2.001]]
```

, but I get the following result

```
[[-0. -0. -0.]
 [ 3. -0. -0.]
 [ 0.  2.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0. -1. -1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.]]
[[-0.  3.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [-0. -0.  2.  0. -1.  0.]
 [-0. -0.  1.  0. -1.  0.]]
temp1:
[[10.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  5.  3.]
 [ 0.  3.  2.]]
temp2: 
[[0.001 0.    0.   ]
 [0.    0.001 0.   ]
 [0.    0.    0.001]]
result:
[[10  0  0]
 [ 0  5  3]
 [ 0  3  2]]
```

The float values are being completely ignored. I can't understand why this is happening. Just for reference, lambdaa is 0.001 in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the result matrix declaration

```
result = np.array([[0.0,0.0,0.0],
                    [0.0,0.0,0.0],
                    [0.0,0.0,0.0]])
```

worked

Comment: Or even simpler: `result = np.zeros((3, 3))`.  You need to let numpy know that it's a floating point array.  When all the elements are integers, it assumes it can use an int array.